# Gradle: Use central declaration of dependencies in "subprojects" block

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-submodule

I followed Gradle's instructions to a central point to define dependencies. I am using the `libs.version.toml` file to do that. see: [Link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub::toml-dependencies-format)

For this example, let's assume, that i have this `libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
mockito = "4.1.0"
[libraries]
mockito = { module = "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin", version.ref = "mockito" }
```

Now using it in the root or subprojects' `build.gradle` works fine, but when defining the `subprojects` block, where I define dependencies and plugins for all submodules, it does not work. Example root build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    (...)
}

// add dependencies for this module only
dependencies {
    testImplementation(libs.mockito) // works
}

subprojects {
    // add dependencies to every submodule
    dependencies {
        testImplementation(libs.mockito) // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, without adding every dependency to each subprojects' build.gradle? I am using Gradle 8.0.1.

Comment: What does "it does not work" look like? What's the error you get?

Comment: UnknownDomainObjectException: Extension with name 'libs' does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a consequence of the way the `subproject` and `allproject` blocks are implemented in Gradle.

You can make it work by prefixing the `libs` access with `rootProject`:

```
subprojects {
    // add dependencies to every submodule
    dependencies {
        testImplementation(rootProject.libs.mockito) // Now works
    }
}
```

You can find more information about this in the [Gradle issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16634).

However, Grade recommends to replace usage of `allproject` / `subproject` constructs with [convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins).

Comment: Works, thank you. Also I will look into using convention plugins, looks interesting.