# Why does the dependency declared in libs.versions.toml not work in subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm writing a build script for a multi-module project using gradle 8.0.2, declaring some dependencies in the libs.versions.toml file, and my build script is as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:7.1.2")
    }

}

plugins{
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

group = "xxx"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "checkstyle")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
    // common deps + repos
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        api(libs.jsr305)
        testImplementation(libs.bundles.junit)

        compileOnly(libs.lombok)
        annotationProcessor(libs.lombok)

        testCompileOnly(libs.lombok)
        testAnnotationProcessor(libs.lombok)
    }

    java {
        withSourcesJar()
    }

    tasks.named<Test>("test") {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }

    tasks.withType<Javadoc>() {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

I want to apply these common dependencies in each subproject, which are defined in libs.versions.toml, and I can guarantee that libs.versions.toml is written without problems, but I can't get it to work in subprojects

Error:

```
Extension with name 'libs' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext, base, defaultArtifacts, sourceSets, reporting, javaToolchains, java, testing, checkstyle, publishing, shadow]

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: Extension with name 'libs' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext, base, defaultArtifacts, sourceSets, reporting, javaToolchains, java, testing, checkstyle, publishing, shadow]
```

Comment: Rename your `libs` to `rootProject.libs`. The answer was given here: Here is a dup with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75547262/gradle-use-central-declaration-of-dependencies-in-subprojects-block

Answer (score -3):

Gradle recommends using this:

[Convention Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins)

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific with your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).